# Singular/plural searches and stemming

Tags: search, stemming

I'm discovering a simple solution for singular-plural keywords searches. I heard about stemming but I don't want to use all its features, only plural/singular transformation. The language is Dutch. Have looked at http://www.snowball.tartarus.org before. Does anyone know the simple solution for singular|plural relevant searches?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary, a list of stopwords (those you don't want to singularize) plus the rules for the language. If you don't know Dutch then I cannot help you, but show you how it'd be done in Spanish, for instance:

- Plurals end with s, if it doesn't then it's done

  - If it ends with s,

    - check if it's a verb or conjugation ending with s if it is one, then it's done (verbs could be added to the stopwords list)
    - if it's not a verb, remove s
    - if the word exists in the dictionary, done
    - if it doesn't remove the previous letter, and check it in the dictionary.
    - if it's still not there it's an exception you'll need to check manually to code in the exceptions (I cannot right now think of any, but they always exist :)

Of course this will not translate directly to Dutch.

In general stemmers are already done and provide most of what you need, why don't you want them?

Answer (score 1):

Stemmers caused much user annoyance, so if I use one of them, all functionality except singular/plural should be disabled. So the requirement is to use only plural/singular transformations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct, but it's worth mentioning that the Dutch language has a large number of irregular verbs.  This makes stemming more of a table lookup problem than a set of single rules.

You'll need access to a corpora, you can find one for the Dutch language here: http://corpus1.mpi.nl/ds/imdi_browser/